# Is it possible to add a Legend to Temporal animation in QGIS

Tags: temporal-controller

I have a Temporal animation that shows the movement of tracked squirrels in the forest, there is a  different colour for each animal.  If I add a legend showing colours to the map it doesn't show in the animation.  I have got around this so far by using the Title Decoration but can only have an entry as "1323 = Yellow".  I would be better to show the colour.  I would apreciate any ideas how to acheive this.

Answer (score 2):

A legend can be added by using Decoration-Image.  Write legend in Gimp with appropriate colours, make background transparent and export as png.  Then import with Decoration-Image and place where required.